Optimization on Financial Data in python
I am trying to calculate the breakeven price for a given IRR and getting stuck in scope's root solver. A simple example:
n = 10. # no of periods
years = np.arange(n) + 1
initial_investment = [-1000]
quantity_sold = np.full(n, 20)
price = np.full(n, 20)
revenue = quantity_sold * price
expense = np.full(n, 50)

cash_flow = np.concatenate([initial_investment, revenue - expense])

With this we can calculate the IRR and verify that we get NPV of 0 using numpy_financial:
npf.irr(cash_flow), npf.npv(0.32975, cash_flow)
# (0.32975, 0.008)

What I want to do is the opposite: say, given an IRR of 40%, what is the cash_flow needed for break-even price (NPV = 0).
I am using scipy.optimize.root but getting lost as how to structure that. I can invert npf.npv to get IRR:
optimize.root(npf.npv, args=cash_flow, x0=0.5)

but cash_flow is an array, even allowing for the values of that array to be constant. How would I solve for cash_flow given an IRR?

This doesn't run: you can't pass 10. (a float) to the shape parameter of np.full.

By definition, the net present value for the IRR should be exactly 0, not 0.008; 0.008 is only seen if you truncate the rate. So is that just a validation step?

@Reinderien just a validation. Which is why i passed a truncated value.

It's certainly possible, but it's not very meaningful unless you further constrain the problem (by, for example, fixing the initial investment). Otherwise, the system is underdetermined:
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

n = 10  # no of periods
years = np.arange(1, 1 + n)
initial_investment = -1000
quantity_sold = np.full(shape=n, fill_value=20)
price = np.full(shape=n, fill_value=20.)
revenue = quantity_sold * price
expense = np.full(shape=n, fill_value=50.)
cash_flow = np.concatenate(((initial_investment,), revenue - expense))

# Forward calculation of IRR, shown without use of `npf`
def npv(rate: float) -> float:
    return (cash_flow / (1 + rate)**np.arange(cash_flow.size)).sum()
result = scipy.optimize.root_scalar(f=npv, x0=0.5, bracket=(0, 1))
assert result.converged
irr = result.root
assert np.isclose(0.32975, irr, atol=0, rtol=1e-5)
np.isclose(0, npv(irr), rtol=0, atol=1e-12)
print('irr =', irr)

# Back-calculation of cash flow, again without `npf`
def npv_from_series(cash_flow: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return (cash_flow / (1 + irr)**np.arange(cash_flow.size)).sum()
result = scipy.optimize.least_squares(
    fun=npv_from_series,
    x0=np.concatenate(((-1,), np.ones(n))),
    bounds=scipy.optimize.Bounds(
        lb=np.concatenate(((-np.inf,), np.zeros(n))),
        ub=np.concatenate(((0,), np.full(shape=n, fill_value=np.inf))),
    ),
)
assert result.success
cash_flow = result.x
print(f'Cash flow for IRR of {irr:.1%}:')
print(cash_flow)
print(f'NPV error: {result.fun[0]:.2e}')

irr = 0.3297531334357468
Cash flow for IRR of 33.0%:
[-3.32043506  0.99765753  1.06177051  1.11807742  1.17345293  1.23855932
  1.33771217  1.5628038   3.13235102  0.0914474   0.674785  ]
NPV error: 1.80e-16

If you do fix the initial investment, it's still underdetermined, but at least tends to have a sensible scale:
# Back-calculation of cash flow, again without `npf`
def npv_from_series(profit: np.ndarray) -> float:
    cash_flow = np.concatenate(((initial_investment,), profit))
    return (cash_flow / (1 + irr)**np.arange(cash_flow.size)).sum()
result = scipy.optimize.least_squares(
    fun=npv_from_series,
    x0=np.ones(n),
    bounds=scipy.optimize.Bounds(lb=np.zeros(n)),
)
assert result.success
profit = result.x
print(f'Profit series for IRR of {irr:.1%} and investment of ${-initial_investment:.2f}:')
print(profit)
print(f'NPV error: {result.fun[0]:.2e}')

irr = 0.3297531334357468
Profit series for IRR of 33.0% and investment of $1000.00:
[577.58634499 435.70855853 328.53386135 247.66502124 186.69665115
 140.76042784 106.16648717  80.12334345  60.5226813   45.77384425]
NPV error: -2.49e-14

If you aggressively constrain the problem by assuming constant profit, the profit can be found analytically:
constant_profit = -initial_investment/(
    (1 + irr)**np.arange(-1, -1-n, -1)
).sum()
print(f'For IRR of {irr:.1%} and investment of ${-initial_investment:.2f}, '
      f'assumed-constant profit of ${constant_profit:.2f} over {n} years')

For IRR of 33.0% and investment of $1000.00, assumed-constant profit of $350.00 over 10 years

Yet another constrained solution is to fix the NPV terms to a constant value. This makes the profit a geometric series whose compound growth equals the IRR:
profit = -initial_investment/n*(1 + irr)**np.arange(1, 1+n)
print(f'For IRR of {irr:.1%} and investment of ${-initial_investment:.2f}, '
      f'constant-term profit over {n} years is')
cash_flow = np.concatenate(((initial_investment,), profit))
print(profit)
print(f'NPV error: {npv(irr):.2e}')

For IRR of 33.0% and investment of $1000.00, constant-term profit over 10 years is
[ 132.97531334  176.82433959  235.13271964  312.66847071  415.77187865
  552.87395843  735.18587862  977.61572575 1299.98757461 1728.66255077]
NPV error: 0.00e+00


@Reinderian I appreciate the detailed solution; will check when I get back to my keyboard. I hear your comment about meaningfulness. This is part of a larger problem I’m working on.
